# Create Order or OrderLine bean first?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am creating 2 CMP beans Order and OrderLine.
They have one to many relationship and the problem is:
- If I create the Order bean first, I need a collection of OrderLineLocal to set for the CMR field
- but if I create the OrderLine first, I need an OrderLocal to set for the CMR field
Can anyone help me to solve the problem please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by creating the Order first without adding the collection of OrderLineLocal
Then create series of OrderLine and adding it to a Collection
Then use the setOrderLineCollection() of Order bean after all.